# Reading character devices in linux

Tags: c, linux, character, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I read the device file /dev/hidraw0 when in the terminal by typing 
cat /dev/hidraw0
as the hidraw0 was the usb mouse, the output was a sequence of characters. This sequence was generated as I moved the mouse, clicked and scrolled.

Then I also tried this with a C program. the code is,

```
include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
            FILE *ptr_file;
            char buf[1000];

            ptr_file =fopen("/dev/hidraw0","r");
            if (!ptr_file)
                return 1;

            char c;
            while (1)
            {
                c=fgetc(ptr_file);
                if(c != NULL)
                    printf("%c",c);
                else
                    printf(""); 
            }           

        fclose(ptr_file);
            return 0;
    }
```

this also generated the same (I suppose) sequence of characters. But in a very asynchronous manner. It didn't get updated as quickely as the cat /dev/hidraw0 command.

Why this happens ?

Comment: You create a buffer, yet are reading a single character...

Comment: You could also learn more about muliplexing syscalls like http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable `ptr_file` buffering by calling [`setvbuf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setvbuf/) with `_IONBF`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you flush the stdout after printf, `fflush(stdout);`?